# textfield: appending text has no effect

Tags: javascript

I have a piece of code which displays a div when I enter text into a textfield. It works fine. Now I want to enter text by cloning the text of a button into the textfield. The text shows up in the textfield, but the div doesn't show up.

```js
function addText(event) {
  var targ = event.target || event.srcElement;
  document.getElementById("user_notation").value += targ.textContent || targ.innerText;
}
```

```html
<input id="user_notation">
<button onclick="addText(event)">C</button>
```

Comment: Why the jQuery tag?

Comment: Are you using the words 'button' and 'div' interchangeably?  I ask due to your use of class="div".

Comment: You don't have a `<div>`. Could that be why it doesn't show up?

Comment: are you trying to dislay same content in div ??

Comment: are looking for something like this  - http://codepen.io/nagasai/pen/VmRbOJ

Comment: class="div" has no meaning in this context. Just for applying css.

Comment: Thanks Naga Sai A,

Comment: Thanks Naga Sai A, but the app which I'm using shows a div when I enter text manually, but not when I add text by cloning, unless I press 'enter' on my keyboard.

Answer (score 0):

You've to call the show function that shows the value in the div at the ned of `.addText()` :

```
function addText(event) {
  var targ = event.target || event.srcElement;
  document.getElementById("user_notation").value += targ.textContent || targ.innerText;

  showText(); //Show value in div
}
```

```js
function addText(event) {
  var targ = event.target || event.srcElement;
  document.getElementById("user_notation").value += targ.textContent || targ.innerText;
  
  showText();
}

document.getElementById("user_notation").addEventListener('input', showText, false);

function showText(){
    document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = document.getElementById("user_notation").value;
}
```

```html
<input id="user_notation">
<button onclick="addText(event)">C</button>
<div id="result"></div>
```

Comment: Unfortunately, not working. i think I need something like a combination of focus on the textfield and a simulation of a keystroke (enter)

Comment: Please it's not clear what you want exactly.. try to describe the desired behavior.

Answer (score 0):

To achieve expected use below option

HTML:

```
<input id="user_notation" onkeyup ="showDiv()">
<button class="div" onclick="addText(event)" >C</button>
<div id="div">showing DIV</div>
```

JS:

```
  document.getElementById("div").style.visibility = 'hidden';
function addText(event) {
var targ = event.target || event.srcElement;
document.getElementById("user_notation").value += targ.textContent ||     targ.innerText;

}

function showDiv(){

  var textboxVal = document.getElementById("user_notation").value;

  if(textboxVal.length>0){
  document.getElementById("div").style.visibility = 'visible';
}
  else{
     document.getElementById("div").style.visibility = 'hidden'; 
  }
}
```

http://codepen.io/nagasai/pen/VmRbOJ